# Book where a group of shapeshifting teens band together to fix a carousel

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, shape-shifter

I will preface that I do not know if it's a series or not but I do have a feeling it might be.

Female main character that is one of the panthers (with dyed fur). There are only two shapeshifters of the same species because the carousel only had pairs. Do not remember the call to action but it might have been a thunderstorm that struck the carousel or a petition to scrap the ride. MC and a few others track down the scattered ride animals, one I know was in an antique shop. May have been a second thunderstorm after the carousel was put back together, MC and love interest have to go into hiding I think.

The thunderstorm is what gave them their powers, and the carousel animals are what the shapeshifters are, two panthers, two horses, etc.

There's not much else I remember; I read this in like 2014-2017 so the details are a little fuzzy.

Comment: Shapeshifting teens fixing a merry-go-round in a  vicious lightning storm. How terribly mundane...

Comment: This is a text novel, not a graphic novel?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1916564-abandoned-children-s-book-about-a-carousel-horse-that-comes-to is probably not about the same book, but has a couple lists of books about carousels.

Comment: Closest match I've found so far is https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2849843-the-carousel, but of course it's two sisters as the protagonists, and just horses. And I don't think any storm.